# Using ng-repeat with partial url inside ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to use ng-repeat to spit out part of a url (my.url) within ng-include. Unfortunately I cant seem to get it to work. It works when I dont place it within an ng-include, so I know that part isnt the issue. THe issue seems to be when I place {{my.url}} inside ng-repeat and attached to the first (static) part of the url.

What i am aiming for is the ng-include to use "filepath/filepath/mypage.html

my.url is the mypage.html bit.

Anybody able to advise?

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="stuff in myList" heading="{{my.text}}" class="sg-tabbed-titles">
<div class="tab">
  <ul class="tabbed-list">
    <li class="tab-content">
         <div ng-include="'\filepath/filepath/{{my.url}}\'"></div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<div ng-include="'filepath/filepath/' + my.url"></div>
```

`ngInclude` takes expression. It means that you need to use normal string concatenation just like you would do in regular javascript code.

Comment: Thanks. this has successfully printed out all the file names in the folder. Although not in the fashion I was hoping for. I was hoping to produce a scenario where a tab is created and the contents of each file where printed out into each tab content. But that is probably a different question.